# replicating a web application functionality in iPad app

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, webview

How can I replicate a web application's following functionality in an iOS app: Do a successful login, click on a button and load a new webpage

This is what I plan to do: In the iOS app, I can invoke a new URL upon button click, pass login credentials and get the required webpage from server and load in a webview.

Is there any other approach to achieve this? Without invoking a new URL, when I click the button in iPad, can I somehow login to the web application (in iPad's browser) and show the page in the browser?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You want to be automatically logged in your native iPad app if you are already logged in your iPad web application?